# Php Basics Create Object

Tags: php

```
<?php

$myClass = new MyClass;
$myClass->myFunc();

class MyClass 
{
    public static function myFunc() {
        echo 'testcall';
    }
}

?>
```

Does php go from top to bottom?

If so why does php know MyClass at the moment where I create an instance of it?

Comment: php goes from top to bottom but when if found any function,variable declaration or class instantiate then it will load those first and then go to next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of forward declaration in PHP, instead you need to have the class declared in current script even if it's after the object invocation. but for any included script include statement needs to be executed before you create instance of that class.

That's why your code works.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP there is no need of declaration previously, You can use it at the time of using it that variable.Your code is working as you included it in the same file

At the time of declaring class in another .php file you have to include it compulsory before initiating the object of that particular class.

Hope it is useful to you :)